# Workaround to avoid React import at head of each file using Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs

It seems pretty absurd that at the beginning of each component file or each layout or each routing file, I have to import React, ReactMounter and stuff like that.

Is there any way around this? Ideally I would love to have each JSX file simply have the definition of something like `ReactComponentAlpha = React.createComponent(...);` without crap at the header.

Comment: It does not seem absurd to me. It makes your dependencies explicit and saves namespace pollution, and also makes your code more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Well having an explicit import in every file/module so that you always know what you are working is sort of the point. But you can try to work around that if you like by importing `React` into your global scope by assigning it explicitly to a global reference. I did not try this, but I think it should work like so:

in `client/main.js`:

```
import _React from 'react';
React = _React;
```

Give it a spin and let me know if it does the job for you.

Comment: "so that you always know what you are working" with?  What else could React mean, why would one be so confused by what React means?  That's like saying I need to keep using your name when I talk to you so I don't forget who I'm talking to.